# MySql iterate in database

Tags: mysql

i have a table example [user_skill table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0LlQ.png)

user can choose the minimum level of a skill. For example `Maths => Beginner` where Maths has `ID=1` and Beginner `ID=1`
From the frontend side i get with POST payload in a array

```
['skill_id' => 2, 'knowledge' => 1],
['skill_id' => 5, 'knowledge' => 3]
```

the max value of `knowledge` is 3.
Now i will get from the table all `user_id` which meet the conditions,

```
['skill_id' => 2, 'knowledge' => 1]
['skill_id' => 2, 'knowledge' => 2]
['skill_id' => 2, 'knowledge' => 3]
['skill_id' => 5, 'knowledge' => 3]
```

that's mean, i will all `user_id` which has this specific `skill_id` but with all `knowledge` up to 3.

How can i do this in MySql? Or the only one way is to iterate, on the backend side, through all users and check if the conditions are true?

Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain the expected output a bit more clearly? "i will all user_id which has this specific skill_id but with all knowledge up to 3." part is a bit confusing on what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```sql
select * from user_skill where skill_id in (?) and knowledge >= ? and knowledge <= ?
```

The `?` represent the values that will change. Would suggest you to use prepared statements if possible to substitute the `?`. Otherwise can substitute and test them manually as well if you want.

Refer the example I made at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd0f2b6/4

Comment: Thank you for answer. In your example i will also get 
`['skill_id' => 5, 'knowledge' => 1]`,`['skill_id' => 5, 'knowledge' => 2]`, `['skill_id' => 5, 'knowledge' => 3]` and that is wrong.